# Get list of items in android activity

Tags: android

I am wondering if there is a way to obtain in an array or list all the items that I have in my activity, like the buttons, image-view,text-view, etc. with its coordinates.
I am doing an applications that receives coordinates and it must search if there is any item  in that coordinate, if it finds a button for example, it must perform button action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this two methods helps you

```
private boolean isAViewHere(int x,int y){
        for(View view:getContainedViews())
        {
            int viewX,viewY,width,height;
            int [] location =new int[2] ;
            view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            viewX = location[0];
            viewY = location[1];
            view.measure(0, 0);
            width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            if(x>=viewX&&x<(viewX+width)&&y>=viewY&&y<(viewY+height))
                return true;
        }
        return false ;
    }

private ArrayList<View> getContainedViews(){
        ArrayList<View> res = new ArrayList<View>();
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        if(rootView instanceof ViewGroup) //to be safe ;
        {
            ViewGroup containerView =(ViewGroup)rootView;
            for(int i=0;i<containerView.getChildCount();i++)
            {
                res.add(containerView.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to obtain a reference to the activity's external view. This can be done
by calling

```
 ViewGroup externalView =(ViewGroup)v.getParent();
```

v being any view which had been previously obtained by findViewById()

once you have the externalView then, if you are only interested in 1st level children
you can simply iterate over its content:

```
int numChilds = externalView.getChildCount();

for (int i = 0; i < numChilds; ++i) {
    View child = externalView.getChildAt(i);
    // and process child
}
```

if, however, you are interested in all child views in all levels, use recursion:

```
void processAllLevels(View v) {

   // process v

   if (!(v instanceof ViewGroup)) {
       // only views of type ViewGroup has children
       return;
   }

   ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)v;
   int numChilds = container.getChildCount();

   for (int i = 0; i < numChilds; ++i) {
        View child = container.getChildAt(i);
        // process child
   }

}
```

And start the recursion by calling:

```
processAllLevels(externalView);
```

Note - the above can only be created *after* setContentView() was called.

Note 2 - when it comes to dense activities the above logic might work slow.